# How to bind class properties in XAML of xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

I have class given as below -

```
public static class ColorResources
    {

        public static readonly Color ListTextColor = Color.Blue;

    }
```

And any xaml file having control like -

```
  <Button Text="Create Account" TextColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="ListTextColor" Clicked="btnCreateAcc_clicked"/>
```

Lets Say I want BackgroundColor of button which is declared in my class file. How to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by declaring a new namespace in your XAML and use it.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:color="clr-namespace:MyApp">
<Button Text="Create Account" TextColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.ListTextColor}" Clicked="btnCreateAcc_clicked"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Your class should look like this

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace MyApp
{
    public static class ColorResources
    {
        public static readonly Color ListTextColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Make sure that the namespace you are declaring in the XAML is the same as the namespace in your class. In this case *MyApp*