# Xamarin Forms Platform Specific Image Source Binding in xaml

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I am trying to bind Image source in xaml in Xamarin forms but I get the following  error.

> Cannot assign property "iOS": type mismatch between
>   "Xamarin.Forms.Binding" and "Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource"

I can however hardcode the image source but I will have to do it in many places, so I would prefer binding it to a property which if changed can be reflected throughout the project. Can anyone cast some light on the error I am getting?

I am currently using the converter class to retrieve the source. Below is my current code that is producing error. Also, I do not want to move to code based solution and would rather see if this can be resolved in XAML.

```
<Image 
    Aspect="AspectFill"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="3"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="End">

    <Image.Source>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
            iOS="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource getGestureIcon},ConverterParameter=Swipe}"
            Android="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource getGestureIcon},ConverterParameter=LongPress}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating and using OnPlatform doesn't have Binding support. In your converter check what platform your are on.

Answer (score 0):

@Rui Marinho: I never thought of it that way. That might work. However, I implemented it in a different way, i.e. defining a static property and directly referencing it. used solution from [How to bind class properties in XAML of xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186399/how-to-bind-class-properties-in-xaml-of-xamarin-forms?rq=1)

Below is the code.

```
xmlns:Icon="clr-namespace:GetIcon"

 <Image 
  Aspect="AspectFill"
  Grid.Row="0"
  Grid.Column="2"
  Grid.RowSpan="2"
  VerticalOptions="Center"
  HorizontalOptions="End">
  <Image.Source>
  <OnPlatform 
    x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"
    iOS="{x:Static Icon:GetIcon.SwipeLeft}"
    Android="{x:Static Icon:GetIcon.LongTap}" />
  </Image.Source>
 </Image>
```